# Calculating weighted Average From DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

---

Hi every one.
I have a DB shown in the following picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sjro.jpg)

Every season, every personnel could have one or more posts and every post is in a specific unit. My question is how to calculate weighted AVG for every personnel in each related posts (note that we have two types of criteria where ct.ID = 1 OR 2). I did something as below

```
select r.EvaluaTEDID,r.PostID, Avg(r.FirstScore*iif(ct.id=1,p.COMCrtWeight/100,0))+
                            Avg(r.FirstScore*iif(ct.id=2,p.PROCrtWeight/100,0)) as 'AVG'
from results r
inner join post p on r.PostID = p.ID
inner join job j on p.JobID = j.ID
inner join subcrt sc on r.SubCrtID = sc.ID
inner join Crt c on sc.CrtID = c.ID
inner join CrtType ct on c.CrtTypeID = ct.ID
where r.SeasonID = 4 and j.UnitID = 3068
group by r.EvaluaTEDID, r.PostID
```

but MSSQLS showed 46 which is the weighted average of all records for personnel with ID=8. The desired answer should be 87 (36+51)

COMCrtWeight=40,PROCrtWeight=60

ct.ID for SubCID=6 is 2 and ct.ID for SubCID=1 & 4 is 1

seasonID - EvaluaTEDID - SubCID - PostID - Score

4 ------------ 8 ------------------ 6 ----------- 26 ------ 90

4 ------------ 8 ------------------ 1 ----------- 26 ------ 90

4 ------------ 8 ------------------ 4 ----------- 26 ------ 90

I also did something like this:

```
select EvaluaTEDID, sum(WeightedSum) from
(select r.EvaluaTEDID,r.PostID,     
avg(r.FirstScore*iif(ct.id=1,p.COMCrtWeight/100,p.PROCrtWeight/100))
                                                                as WeightedSum from results r
inner join post p on r.PostID = p.ID
inner join job j on p.JobID = j.ID
inner join subcrt sc on r.SubCrtID = sc.ID
inner join Crt c on sc.CrtID = c.ID
inner join CrtType ct on c.CrtTypeID = ct.ID
where r.SeasonID = 4 and j.UnitID = 3068
group by ct.id, r.EvaluaTEDID, r.PostID)
group by EvaluaTEDID
```

Buy I got syntax error.

Could you please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: EvaluatedID is personnel ID

Comment: 90*40/100 = 36 AND Avg(90*60/100,80*60/100) = 51 AND final weighted score should be 87.